# API Gateway with microservices and presentation layer

Tags: cloud, microservices, soa, cloud-foundry, api-gateway

I am working on microservices architecture and using API gateway pattern to secure the services and everything looks good so far.
We have presentation layer/orchestration layer(a monolith RoR application) that is supposed to orchestrate the microservices for a user functionality.
We are deploying everything to our company's enterprise PAAS platform. My question is should i make the presentation layer fall beneath the API gateway(or not)? 
What could be the PROS/CONS of the approach?

Comment: Can i get some feedback here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided that the microservices should fall under the API gateway and everything else would be the microservices client consuming those microservices through the API gateway.